# Dynamic Arrays for earlier Excel versions

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, array

Is there a way to have an array formula "spill over" in earlier Excel versions? I have heard that the new Excel will bring dynamic arrays, but need this functionality on an older version of Excel.

I have an existing column of names in column A (ex: Jane, Sam, Joe) and I want column B to automatically adjust to changes made to column A. So if I add or delete a row from column A, B will also add/delete that row and be identical to column A, but through using a formula of some sort.

I would imagine it would look something like `{=A:A}` in the B column.

Comment: When you say "spill over", are you asking about a way to accomplish a similar result  using native functionality in an older version that doesn't have the new feature, or a way to add the new feature to the old version, like copying a code module or something?  BTW, this recent thread may be interesting for you: [@ in the beginning of a formula](https://superuser.com/q/1471013/364367)

Comment: @fixer1234 I am asking about a way to accomplish what is being done in the newer version using the older versions (and it is ok to use VBA if needed). The answer given in the link you provided is related to what I am asking.

Answer (score 1):

An [array formula](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7) would indeed do the job.
If your original table is in column A of "SheetA", create an new sheet, select the *whole* A column and type `=SheetA!A:A` and then (important) hit `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER`.

Array formulas are very powerful but I confess they are a bit tricky to master. The incoming dynamic array functions seem much easier to use.

Edit: not sure I got you there. If the 2 columns are adjacent, and you remove or insert an entire row, both columns are affected.

Edit2: as discussed below, if you want no zeros in your column, you may use `=IF(SheetA!A:A="","",SheetA!A:A)` instead [image]

Comment: This works, but it seems to slow down the workbook considerably. Is there a way to avoid all of the unnecessary #N/A errors that pop up for rows where there isn't a corresponding value in the other sheet?

Comment: A way of adressing the slowing is to select part of the A colmun (ie the 500 first cells if you're sure that data in Sheet A will never be more than 500 long).


Regarding your #N/As, I have none here, but I get zeros. A way of fixing that is to type `=IF(SheetA!A:A="","",SheetA!A:A)` instead of only =SheetA!A:A.